# storm: KafkaSpout - where is my consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I need to see the offset values that storm is using to read via its **KafkaSpout**. Here is the config I pass in:

```
SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts, "some_values",  
     "/storm/env_values", "storm_DEBUG");
```

I've tried searching about with some of the kafka tools but haven't found anything useful yet:

- kafka.tools.ExportZkOffsets
- kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker

Are there better tools to use to find my offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that I was looking at the wrong zookeeper. According to [this doc](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.1/bk_user-guide/content/ch_storm-using-ingest-connectors.html):

> The Kafka spout stores its offsets in the same instance of Zookeeper used by Apache Storm.

So looking at the kafka zookeeper isn't going to be v helpful.

Comment: It depends, where do you decide to store your offsets, can be in kafka zookeeper or storm zookeeper or in a dedicate zookeeper server. You can config where store offset.

Comment: You can configure to use kafka's zookeeper by setting the property STORM-ZOOKEEPER-PORT to 2181. When run in local mode, I think it defaults to use port 2000, which is the zookeeper storm uses by default.  I was reprocessing all the messages from the beginning whenever I restart storm. With this fix, I don't see them ever. Another symptom of this issue is you would see NoNode errors for wherever your zk consumer offsets are stored.

Answer (score 3):

KafkaSpout maintains the offset information on Storm's zookeeper by default under `{root path}/{id}/{partition-id}`.  Read [this](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka) for more information.

You can use the bundled zookeeper shell in Kafka (`bin/zookeeper-shell.sh zookeeperHost:port`) and browse to the location using the CLI. Issuing a get against the offset path will give you the stored value.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem
in Managment consoles there is a list of tools for monitoring your topics and offsets. I remember i have use https://github.com/otoolep/stormkafkamon a python monitoring tool.

But what exactly do you want?, if you only tried to see your offset you can see your offset in zookeeper, only connect in your zookeeper where your offsets are stored.

Example:

> bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2000

Connecting to localhost:2000

> Welcome to ZooKeeper! JLine support is disabled
>
> ls /
>
> [storm, brokers, zookeeper]
>
> ls /brokers
>
> [kafka-spout]
>
> ls /brokers/kafka-spout
>
> [partition_0]
>
> get /brokers/kafka-spout/partition_0
>
> {"topology":{"id":"a9be1962-6b4e-4ed4-ae68-155a1948a1f6","name":"consolidate_reports"},**"offset":4426029**,"partition":0,"broker":{"host":"localhost","port":9092},"topic":"bid_history"}
>   cZxid = 0x50 ctime = Thu May 21 11:00:48 BRT 2015 mZxid = 0x50 mtime =
>   Thu May 21 11:00:48 BRT 2015 pZxid = 0x50 cversion = 0 dataVersion = 0
>   aclVersion = 0 ephemeralOwner = 0x0 dataLength = 182 numChildren = 0